# Camera intent problem, camera is starting without request

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have a little problem with my camera intent. As I know, when camera orientation is changed, activity is restarted. Okej, I am using the code bellow.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    app = (myApplication)getApplication(); 

    if(savedInstanceState ==null ) getFullImage(null);
    else{
        String somevalue = savedInstanceState.getString("uri");
        getFullImage(somevalue);
        }
}

private void getFullImage(String testValue)
{   if(testValue == null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), UUID.randomUUID()+ ".jpg");
    outputFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFile);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

}else 
{   
    outputFile = null;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = new File(testValue);
    outputFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, testValue);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    finishFromChild(getParent());
}
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Back Button"); 
        finishFromChild(this);
    } 
    else
     if(requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {   
    //I'm creating new file here (for this question is irelevant)
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), com.test.activities.SaveFileActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("image", newPath);
        startActivityFromChild(this, myIntent, SAVE_ITEM);  
        finishFromChild(this);
    }
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("uri",outputFile.getPath());
}
```

After picture is captured, I press DONE button and I go to SaveFileActivity. Everyting works fine, until I try from SaveFIleActivity to go to another activity, then camera is starting again. Where should I look for the problem ? Maybe I should kill camera intent, but when ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want to be using the simpler `startActivity()` and `finish()` methods instead of `startActivityFromChild()` and `finishFromChild()`. I admit, however, that I'm a bit unclear as to what the use of the ones you are actually for.

Comment: No result that way. Ok, to be more clear, I have three screens. HomeActivity, CameraActivity, SaveFileActivity. The main activity is HomeActivity from where i press button "theCamera". Then I call CameraActivity(code is in this question) and after I press DONE button it goes to SaveFileActivity. In SaveFileActivity I have button "save", and after this button is clicked it should go back to main HomeActivity. But instead of HomeActivity it goes to CameraActivity.  I guess CameraActivity is never killed. Why ?

Comment: "No result", as in using that doesn't solve the problem, or it doesn't return a result?

Comment: Once you call "finish()" from an activity, it should be removed from the back stack, so that going back (by finishing the "save" activity") shouldn't start it again.

Comment: "No result", as doesn't solve the problem. :) Maybe in method getFullImage I must kill the activity before start it again ? But I don't know how. The method getFullImage is starting two times, first with value testValue =null then with some value.

Comment: Ah, I suspect the second time it's called is when you come back from the camera activity and it needs to recreate your activity. As your code starts off the camera each time your activity is created, you are just getting it started for a second time. onActivityResult() gets called before onResume() (and possibly immediately after onCreate() if the system had to destroy the activity for memory reasons).

Comment: So, rework your code so that you don't always start the camera in onCreate(). Also, switch to the simpler methods as mentioned in the answer body. I'm fairly certain you're using the other methods incorrectly.